# initiate a flask Request object and modify it

Tags: flask, request

Is it possible to create a flask request object and modify it? I try with

```
from flask import Request
r = Request({})
r.method = 'GET'
```

But I get an error `raise AttributeError("read only property")`

Comment: Which version are you on? I don't get this on `2.0.2`.

Comment: @BasvanderLinden, Any solution with any version is fine with me. I put it as an example only.

Comment: I meant that your example code is working for me. I can't reproduce the problem, so I was wondering if it was due to the Flask version you're running.

Answer (score 1):

In general you use flask to handle requests, but if you want to generate a request object you can use `Request.from_values`. Maybe what you are looking is something like this:

```
import json
from flask import Request

data = {
    "key1": "value1",
    "key2": "value2",
    "key3": "value3"
}

request = Request.from_values(headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'}, data=json.dumps(data), method="POST")
```

So you can change anything you want creating the request. Here is also a page with [examples](https://python.hotexamples.com/examples/werkzeug/Request/from_values/python-request-from_values-method-examples.html#google_vignette).